# "position: sticky;" elements not quite lining up

Tags: html, css

So I run our secondary, cheesy school website for students. Summer just started so I'm doing a bunch of work on it. I have three button tags, and all of their positions are set to sticky. When I scroll down, they line up flush with the top of the page (because I set top: to 0px;). But when the page is scrolled up, they are offset by about two pixels from the top. But it's super obvious, and I think it looks ugly. There is also a lot of spacing between them. It would be nice to get rid of those two. The first button lines up how I want it. It just contains text. The other two, that don't line up, have  elements around them, and contain images. I think this Is why, but I am struggling to solve the problem. I'm posting this late at night, so I can't check any answers for another 10 hours or so. But It would be nice to have some help, Thanks.

PS, My website address is https://jeffthecow.com/
The class of all three buttons is "openbtn".

[image: Element Image]

Comment: Try getting them to line up by themselves inside a single `<div>`, then set that `<div>` to `position: sticky`. (At worst, that means making the question simpler.)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? Thanks!

Comment: I agree with@Ry- - but the reason for your issue is that the first button is a button element and the other 2 are 'a' elements that wrap around the buton. So if you leave it in the structure it is - you need to apply styling to the wrapping a's to ensure they are in the same place as the naked button. That said - there is no reason for them to be in an a element - you can remove that and apply the click handler directly to the buttons and as @Ry- said  puth them all in a single wrapper and apply the sticky to that.

Comment: Thanks @Ry, I'll put some kind of container around them. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to @Ry I have made up a solution. My code looks like this:

```css
.openbtn {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0px;
  color: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  height: 45px;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div style="
    height: 45px;
    position: sticky;
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
    border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
    width: fit-content;
    top: 0;
">
  <button class="openbtn" title="Open Menu" onclick="openNav()" style="
    float: left;
">&#9776;</button>

  <a target="popup" style="padding: 0px;" onclick="window.open('https://jeffthecow.com/webchat/','name','width=510,height=412')"><button class="openbtn" title="Open Chat" style="/* align-self: stretch; */float: center;"><img src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/Svg-Chat.webp"></button></a>

  <a href="#scrollBtnLocation"><button class="openbtn" title="Back To Top" style="
    float: right;
"><img src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/ScrollTop.webp"></button></a>
</div>
```

Also, it doesn't quite look right if you run the snippet, but you get the idea. Pretty much, I took the three buttons, and wrapped them up nice and tight in a div element, and set the div's position to sticky.
[image]